# Estimation of extraterrestrial radiation for latitudes > 66.5° N/S

Tags: meteorology, atmospheric-radiation, insolation

I'm posting here for the first time, so I hope not to violate any community-specific rules.

In [Allen et al. (1998): FAO-56](https://www.fao.org/3/x0490e/x0490e07.htm#radiation) an equation is presented to estimate extraterrestrial radiation Ra for different latitudes from the solar constant, the solar declination and the time of the year:

[image]

This works quite well to replicate most of the pre-computed values given in [Annnex 2, table 2.6](https://www.fao.org/3/X0490E/x0490e0j.htm) - except for the values in the 70-deg-lat row.

I already noticed the computation fails at this point because of the sunset hour angle equation for latitudes > 66.5° N/S, where you end up with `-tan(phi) * tan(delta) > 1`:

[image]

While FAO-56 does not seem to mention any restrictions or alternative equations, [Neitsch et al. (2011): SWAT Theoretical Documentation](https://swat.tamu.edu/media/99192/swat2009-theory.pdf) at least mention the following (p. 32):

> At latitudes above 66.5° or below -66.5°, the absolute value of `-tan(phi) * tan(delta)` can
> exceed 1 and the above equation cannot be used.

Maybe I'm just lacking some basic math knowledge to notice the obvious for a workaround, but from my point of view the limitation makes sense insofar, as there can't be a sunset hour angle by definition if there is no sunset during certain times of the year.

However, I guess another equation might be applicable in this case in order to determine Ra for high latitudes which I'm not aware of yet?

Thank you very much in advance!